# CentOS - command to find and replace a file name pattern if it exists

Tags: bash, shell, centos

Example:

file at **/source/tmp/**

```
abc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

file at destination **/destination/webapp/**

```
abc-1.0.0-06062013.jar
```

how can i write a command, such that it replaces the older file(at destination) with new file (from source)

1. if file pattern `abc-1.0.0<any value>.jar` exists, replace the destination file (`abc-1.0.0-06062013.jar`) with source file (`abc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`).
2. if file pattern `abc-1.0.0<any value>.jar` does not exist at destination, no change

Comment: Yes. I'm sure someone can

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this:

```
find /destination/webapp -type f -name 'abc-1.0.0-*.jar' -exec cp /source/tmp/abc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar {} \
```

Answer (score -1):

user rsync with `−−existing` option (http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/) it will send only files that already exists on destination